# ruby excel to csv adding .0 to zipcodes

Tags: ruby, csv, xls, export-to-csv, zipcode

I'm using ruby to convert excel files to csv files. Here is the function I have written to do so:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'CSV'
require 'roo'

def xls_to_csv(file,temp_filename)
    if file =~ /\.xlsx$/
        excel = Roo::Excelx.new(file)
    else
        excel = Roo::Excel.new(file)
    end 

    output = File.open(temp_filename, "w")

    1.upto(excel.last_row) do |line|
        output.write CSV.generate_line excel.row(line)
    end 
end
```

It works fine, except that after any zip codes in the file it will add a ".0". Here is an example of input data:

```
address state   zip code    name
123 Lane    TX  78705           John Smith
456 Lane    MS  39564           Smohn Jith
```

And once the .xls file is run through the function, here is the CSV output:

```
address,state,zip code,name
123 Lane,TX,78705.0,John Smith
456 Lane,MS,39564.0,Smohn Jith
```

As you can see, the zip codes now have ".0"s after them. Is there anyway to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the data-type for the zip code field in your excel document to be non-numeric or at least an integer instead of decimal? There should be a formatting option.

Comment: +1 @Cyle. People often mistakenly set a zipcode field to a numeric, because, after all, it is a number... kinda... until they realize that leading zeros are gone and they need to enter a compound zipcode like 00000-0000. Instead zipcodes need to be strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roo takes the datatype from the Excel cell type. If you control the spreadsheet, I'd suggest you change the cell type to text.
Otherwise, you can convert it to a string in your script. For example (please note, I haven't tested this locally so it could be wrong):

```
1.upto(excel.last_row) do |line|
    data = excel.row(line)
    data[2] = data[2].to_s
    output.write CSV.generate_line data
end
```

Comment: could you give an example of how I could convert it to a string in my script?

Comment: Except that as @the Tin Man points out, you already have lost the leading zeroes so you will need to sprintf them back in: `data[2] = '%05d' % data[2]`

Comment: Good point pguardiario. I'm not from the US so didn't realise zips could start with zero.